# Override 3rd party templates in Angular

Tags: angular, templates, overriding

Is it possible to override the template of a component which is being used by an external angular component?

i.e component library exports component `A` which is to be used by others. Component `A` however uses component `B` internally. Is it possible to override the template of component `B`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you should be able to do this as long as the Component is exported by the library.

Example:

```js
import { LibComponent } from 'some-lib';

@Component({
    selector: 'same-selector-as-lib',
    template: '../path/to/custom/template.html'
})
export class CustomImplementation extends LibComponent { }
```

If you modify `CustomImplementation` and add new dependencies to the constructor then you will need to call `super(/* super args */)`.

Comment: When you say exposed, do you mean exported by the module?

Comment: Yes. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then I guess this question becomes a duplicate as I assume then it's not possible for non exported components?

Comment: is there a possible solution for non exported components?

Comment: It might be possible but it would be a bit of a hack. You can define your own component with the same inputs as the one you are overriding and then pass it to the base component. Create your own view and use the `exportAs` name to call methods on a hidden version of base component. Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/1OoTw7KmRtf9QadAZcTE?p=preview